# Angularjs - Could not resolve 'stores' from state 'mlogin'

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to redirect after login from one module to another using $state.go.I have added the module in app.js also.still I get the error.Help me  finding a solution.I have gone through many threads but still getting the same error  Could not resolve 'stores' from state 'mlogin' .

my controller.js

```
angular.module('login')
 .controller('loginCtrl', loginCtrl)
 .controller('passwordCtrl', passwordCtrl);


function loginCtrl ($scope,$http,$rootScope,$state, $stateParams,LoginFactory) { 
    $scope.merchant = {};
    $scope.errMsg = null;
    $rootScope.loggedIn = false;
    $rootScope.successmsg = "";
    $scope.loginSubmit = function(valid) {     
        $scope.submit = true;
        if (valid) {
            var data = { "email": $scope.merchant.email, "password": $scope.merchant.password };
            LoginFactory.Login(data).success(function(res) {
                if (res.status == 1) {
                    $rootScope.loggedIn = true; 

                    $state.go('stores');
                } else {
                    $rootScope.loggedIn = false;
                    $scope.errMsg = res.message;
                }
            }).error(function(error) {

            });
        }
    };

    $scope.removeAlert = function(){
        $rootScope.successmsg = false;
    };
};
```

my config file which is in another module - storeConfig.js

```
angular
.module('stores',[])
.config(storesConfig);


function storesConfig($stateProvider,  $compileProvider) {
    $compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled(true);

    $stateProvider.state('stores', {
        url: '/stores?msg',
        templateUrl: "app/stores/view.html",
        controller: "storesCtrl",
        data: {title: "Merchant Stores"},
        resolve: {
            checkLogin: checkLogin
        },
      //  abstract: true,
    }).
            state('add_store', {
                url: '/addstore',
                templateUrl: "app/stores/add.html",
                controller: "addstoreCtrl",
                data: {title: "Add Store"},
                resolve: {
                    checkLogin: checkLogin
                }
            }).
            state('edit_store', {
                url: '/editstore/:id',
                templateUrl: "app/stores/edit.html",
                controller: "editstoreCtrl",
                data: {title: "Edit Store"},
                resolve: {
                    checkLogin: checkLogin
                }
            }).
            state('delete_merchant', {
                url: '/deletemerchant/:id',
                //templateUrl:"app/merchant/edit.html",
                controller: "deletemerchantCtrl",
                data: {title: "Delete Merchant"},
                resolve: {
                    checkLogin: checkLogin
                }
            }).
            state('myaccount', {
                url: '/myaccount',
                templateUrl: "app/merchant/edit.html",
                controller: "editmerchantCtrl",
                data: {title: "Edit Merchant"},
                resolve: {
                    checkLogin: checkLogin
                }
            }).
            state('subscription_merchant', {
                url: '/subscription/:id',
                templateUrl: "app/merchant/subscription.html",
                controller: "subscriptionmerchantCtrl",
                data: {title: "Merchant Details"},
                resolve: {
                    checkLogin: checkLogin
                }
            });
        }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please provide a working example of all your code? You haven't included your `app.js` here and there is no indication of how these modules are working together.

Comment: this is my app.js
(function () {
 angular.module('zomongoMerchantApp', [
    
    
    'capitalizeFilter',
    'ngMaterial',
    'ui.select',
    'ngSanitize',
    'angularPayments',
    'ngMap',
    'ngRoute',
    'ui.router',
    'signup',
    'login',
    'stores',
]);
})(); in my main project i have separated everything in modules,like login module,signup & store module.in each module i have separe config file for stateproviders,controller,views.html,module.js.i have given one of my config file and controller also.this is module file  login.js angular.module('login',[]);

Answer (score 0):

I added module to **separate** file with **empty** `'[]'` and my problem got solved.Code is given below.

```
angular.module('stores',[]);
```